# Change between fonts with a simple click

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

Iam working on a website and I want to show someone the difference between two fonts on the website on different pages.

Is there a way that I can code it that I can switch between fonts easily?

I was thinking about making an second stylesheet with the 2nd font in it and use jQuery to disable/enable the stylesheet. But this means I have to place this on every page there is.

Is there a better way for this?

Comment: There's a few ways you could do this... What have you tried though?

Comment: Create a button that toggles a class on the body tag.

Comment: @option Havent tried anything. have been searching for a solution on google for like an hour but couldnt find anything what I thought what could work so I decided to ask the question here.

Comment: As i understand, you want to change font family of element on click event. Am i right?

Comment: @Mohammad I want to be able to switch the font of the entire website with an on click event, or other way, if that is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use two classes with different fonts and toggle them using JS/jQuery

Comment: But this means I have to put that code on every singe html page right? Or am I wrong...

Comment: I figured im using my footer in an include so I build in in there now. with one click I can change the of the page im at now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that easily with Js/Jquery. 
You just simply toggle a class with different *"font-familys"*.

Here would be a example if you want to change the font in one div:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.font {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FontChange</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    
    <!-- Hosted jQuery libary -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("button").click(function () {
        $(".text").toggleClass("font");
      })
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="text">
      <button>Click me to change the font-family!</button></br>
    
    
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur     sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea I got something like this myself now too. only thing is that when you switch pages the font is resetted to the original one.

Comment: You could use cookies to make it remember the change: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: ah, yes of course @Option - didn't had that idea ;)

Comment: @Option Alright, im looking into this. Do I need to put the jQuery code which toggles the font inside the cookie string?